# Black screen when taking screenshot

Tags: 12.10, xorg, display, intel-graphics, screenshot

I am getting black pictures when I try to take a screenshot with the PrtSc key (which calls Screenshot application).

My graphical system is a Nvidia optimus with Bumblebee installed (the problem happens both on integrated graphics (intel-graphics) mode and with dedicated Nvidia card on).

I recently installed the "intel Linux graphics installer" package (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) and I suspect my problem is related.

Who can help me solve/troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

Comment: facing same problem... dk what to do.. removed the intel software but still no use!! :(